# Can I erase all photo metadata using Gimp?

Tags: gimp, metadata

Gimp 2.10 offers the possibility to change metadata but my question is that if I edit metadata using gimp...

Can I erase all photo metadata using Gimp?

Or it will be some metadata I can not erase using gimp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GIMP 2.9.4 and later has a built-in metadata editor. It is accessed by selecting *Image* -> *Metadata* -> *Edit Metadata*. The GIMP Metadata Editor can edit a wide variety of image metadata fields including GPS metadata. To write metadata click the *Write Metadata* button in the lower right corner of the Metadata Editor window.

[image]
<sup>**GIMP 2.10**</sup>

GIMP 2.10 can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu or as an apt package in Ubuntu 18.10 and later.

Image::ExifTool (*libimage-exiftool-perl*) is a library and program (`exiftool`) to read and write metadata information in multimedia files. To install libimage-exiftool-perl in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

To quickly erase all of an image's metadata run this command:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= /path/to/file
```

Comment: I am currently using GIMP 2.10 and found some post explaining how to edit metadata and it seems it works but I used your input and installed exiftool and just do the trick  too... thanks Karel